# C++ lpcwstr to wstring

Tags: c++, wstring, lpcwstr

I would like to convert a LPCWSTR to wstring in C++ (VS 2010).
I want to use this in OutputDebugStringW().

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well just pass the `LPCWSTR` to the constructor of `wstring` like this:

```
LPCWSTR str=L"fun";
wstring str2(str);
```